# I have an error on 'pip install src' in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I do the command `pip install src`.

I don’t know what the problem is. But I need *src* for code on GitHub.

Error:

```
Collecting src
  Using cached src-0.0.7.zip (6.3 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for src, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: src
    Running setup.py install for src ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\никитос\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\85FC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8btvg43z\\src_380e8f96e17a48c8aa11f51cebd7b5c0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\85FC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8btvg43z\\src_380e8f96e17a48c8aa11f51cebd7b5c0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\85FC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tmhhryto\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\никитос\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\src'
         cwd: C:\Users\85FC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8btvg43z\src_380e8f96e17a48c8aa11f51cebd7b5c0\
    Complete output (2 lines):
    running install
    You've probably made a mistake here and are trying to install from a 'src' directory which doesn't exist.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\никитос\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\85FC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8btvg43z\\src_380e8f96e17a48c8aa11f51cebd7b5c0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\85FC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8btvg43z\\src_380e8f96e17a48c8aa11f51cebd7b5c0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\85FC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tmhhryto\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\никитос\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\src' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for full command output as specified. It would be helpful to see the error from the log. Two possible problems that might cause this (without seeing the log):

1. Windows has a maximum path length which exceeding from might result in problems (260 characters)
2. Try to change your path to use only valid ascii characters and avoid using non ascii such as cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

[`src`](https://pypi.org/project/src/) is a package that [forbids](https://github.com/mitchellrj/src/blob/e533c1452f375010280c13186d031766d277f3d7/setup.py#L66) to install itself. It's not the package you want to install.

Perhaps you want to install something from an `src` directory?

Comment: Yes I want from src intstall UI

Comment: @НикитаДавыдов Sorry but that's meaningless. Not enough information. What `src`, what "install UI"? Show the code (better, point to a repository), give us [mcve].

Comment: ```
from src import UI
from src import GmailnatorRead, GmailnatorGet, dfilter_email, pfilter_email, find_email_type
```

Comment: @НикитаДавыдов I tried to search the Net for `GmailnatorRead`, `GmailnatorGet`, `dfilter_email` — nothing came up. It's some private code, nobody knows about it. Where from did you get it?

Comment: I get this code from github to generate discord acounts.Dont my code

Comment: @НикитаДавыдов Then there must be installation instructions. Please share the Github URL.